# powershell export outlook contacts too slow

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365, office-automation

I'm exporting Outlook contacts to a .csv file using Powershell. Here are the relevant parts of the PS script:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$Contacts = $Outlook.session.GetDefaultFolder(10).items
$count = $Contacts.Count
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = "utf8"

$Contacts | Select * | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation "$outfile"
```

This is on a Windows 10 machine with Office 365. The contacts are in a local .pst file (there is no Exchange server).

It takes 15 minutes to export around 3100 contacts!

Is there a way to make this much faster? Or some other way to export these contacts?

Update:

I tried to use a "Table" object as suggested by Eugene Astafiev below, but without a filter and with Powershell instead of VB. But I cannot get any useful output with what I tried.

This for example:

```
$Folder = $Outlook.session.GetDefaultFolder(10)
$Table = $Folder.GetTable()
while ( $row = $Table.GetNextRow() ) { $row }
```

doesn't print anything useful from the contacts. It only prints

```
Application                                       Class Session            Parent
-----------                                       ----- -------            ------
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass   121 System.__ComObject System.__ComObject
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass   121 System.__ComObject System.__ComObject
... etc.
```

Comment: There are no PowerShell programming bottlenecks in your example, in other words it looks to me as a pure **outlook** limitation issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the [Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.table) object which represents a set of item data from a `Folder` or `Search` object, with items as rows of the table and properties as columns of the table.

The `Table` represents a read-only dynamic rowset of data in a `Folder` object. Use `Folder.GetTable` to obtain a `Table` object that represents a set of items in a folder or search folder. If the `Table` object is obtained from `Folder.GetTable`, you can further specify a filter (in `Table.Restrict`) to obtain a subset of the items in the folder. If you don't specify any filter, you'll obtain all the items in the folder.

By default, each item in the returned `Table` contains only a default subset of its properties. You can regard each row of a Table as an item in the folder, each column as a property of the item, and the Table as an in-memory lightweight rowset that allows fast enumeration and filtering of items in the folder. Although additions and deletions of the underlying folder are reflected by the rows in the `Table`, the `Table` does not support any events for adding, changing, and removing of rows. For more information on default columns in a Table, see [Default Properties Displayed in a Table Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/default-properties-displayed-in-a-table-object).

The following VBA sample code shows how to use the `GetTable` method of the `Folder` class when dealing with the Outlook object model:

```
Sub DemoTable()  
    'Declarations  
    Dim Filter As String  
    Dim oRow As Outlook.Row  
    Dim oTable As Outlook.Table  
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder  
  
    'Get a Folder object for the Inbox  
    Set oFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
  
    'Define Filter to obtain items last modified after January 1, 2022  
    Filter = "[LastModificationTime] > '1/1/2022'"  
    'Restrict with Filter  
    Set oTable = oFolder.GetTable(Filter)  
  
    'Enumerate the table using test for EndOfTable  
    Do Until (oTable.EndOfTable)  
        Set oRow = oTable.GetNextRow()  
        Debug.Print (oRow("Subject"))  
        Debug.Print (oRow("LastModificationTime"))  
    Loop  
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to use Table, but without success. See the updated question.

Comment: You can add the require properties to the table, see the `Table.Columns.Add` method for more information. You can find [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/default-properties-displayed-in-a-table-object#columns-for-the-contacts-folder) property set for the contacts folder in MSDN.